# TypeORM - Pass Entity object through functions

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a lambda called XYZ where I query a User instance in typeorm

```
User { id: 1, name: 'test', status: 'x' }
```

And then i need to pass this User as a payload in a HTTP request for another lambda called ABC

But when I parse the body in ABC lambda, User is not a Entity anymore, but a simple object, so i can't use .save() method to modify User properties

How can I do this?

Comment: You could cast it to User? Typescript is just about type safety it has "nothing" to do with what the object actually represents